# Чтение структуры из бинарного файла

Tags: c++, структуры

У меня есть структура

```
    struct CarInfo
{
    string brand;
    string color;
    string licensePlate;
    string fullName;

};
```

Я хочу прочитать из бинарного файла все записи структур и вывести их на экран, потом дописать в конец файла структуру и снова вывести на экран, это всё делается через функции.
после вывода на экран программа зависает и завершается:
(процесс 8720) завершает работу с кодом -1073741819.
Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. 
**_Pnext** было 0xD507DC.

Функция выглядит вот так:

```
void showAllRecords(string direction, fstream &file, CarInfo item)
{
    vector<CarInfo> recordForOut(numberOfRecords(direction, file, item));
    int i = 0; bool t =  false;
    int countOfRecords = numberOfRecords(direction, file, item);
    file.open(direction, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    while (i < recordForOut.size())
    {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item));
        recordForOut[i] = item;
        i++;

    }
    file.seekg(0);
    file.close();
    for (int j = 0; j < recordForOut.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << j + 1 << " item\n";
        cout << "brand " << recordForOut[j].brand;
        cout << "\ncolor " << recordForOut[j].color;
        cout << "\nfull name " << recordForOut[j].fullName;
        cout << "\nlicense plate " << recordForOut[j].licensePlate << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Пробовал разные варианты, независимо от них всё время появляется одна и та же ошибка.

Comment: Лень искать подходящий дубликат, но проблема здесь очевидна - объекты `std::string` не являются POD типами и запись их байт является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, что Вам это очевидно, однако можете мне сообщить как можно исправить эту проблему?

Comment: есть два способа - сделать тип строки pod типом (например, заменив на `char[100]`, но тут нужно угадать с размером) или написать свой сериализатор/десириализатор. Это сложнее, но эффективнее.

Comment: Используйте xml или json для сохранения в файл. Почему не работает ваш вариант: а вы посмотрите sizeof от вашей структуры (спойлер: размер std::string - 32)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам необходимо хранить именно в бинарном виде, как уже было сказано в комментариях

> объекты std::string не являются POD типами и запись их байт является неопределенным поведением

В связи с этим Вам необходимо либо воспользоваться уже существующими сериализаторами, например [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial?hl=ru) или [boost.serrialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html), или написать свой.